# Fatal error by running ncdf package

Tags: r, fatal-error, netcdf

I downloaded a database from ECAD (European Climate Assessment & Dataset), which consist of precipitation data.

> summary(control)
>   rr ( variable  1 ) has shape 464 201 23376

So it has 23376 timesteps because this is too much for one run, I run everytime step separately. But when try to run a timestep above 12000 I get a fatal error (11000 is not a problem). I except a memory issue, but my laptop does not show memory problems. This step causes the problems: cntlprcp1 = get.var.ncdf(nc=control,varid="rr",start,count).

```
control = open.ncdf(con="rr_0.25deg_reg_v9.0.nc", write=FALSE, readunlim=FALSE)
paste(control$filename,"has",control$nvars,"variables"), fill=TRUE)
lonmat  = matrix(get.var.ncdf(nc=control,varid="longitude"),nrow=464,ncol=201) 
latmat  = matrix(get.var.ncdf(nc=control,varid="latitude"),nrow=201,ncol=464)  
timearr = get.var.ncdf(nc=control,varid="time")      
t1 = julian(x=1, d=1, y=1950,  origin=c(month = 1, day = 1, year = 1601))
targettime = julian(x=7,d=4,y=1980,origin=c(month = 1, day = 1, year = 1601))
inds       = (1:dim(timearr))
tind       = inds[targettime-t1 == timearr]
ndims    = control$var[['rr']]$ndims   
varsize  = control$var[['rr']]$varsize    
start = c(    1,         1,      **16000**)
count = c(varsize[1], varsize[2],    1)
cntlprcp1 = get.var.ncdf(nc=control,varid="rr",start,count)
cntlprcp1[cntlprcp1<0] = NA
x = 1:nrow(cntlprcp1)   # R plots rows along X axis!
y = 1:ncol(cntlprcp1)
image.plot(x,y,cntlprcp1,col=tim.colors())
```

Comment: Your code does not run for me. For one thing, there's a syntax error in line 2 (the call to `paste(...)`). For another, the calls to `julian(...)`  generate `Error in UseMethod("julian") : 
  no applicable method for 'julian' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"`. Also, can you edit your question to include all the libraries you load.

Comment: It is now working, the problem was that the package ncdf only functions properly in a 32-bit environment instead of a 64-bit R.